# What artifacts does Scrum require for application design and systems documentation?

Tags: scrum, documentation, requirements, development-process, design

I have been a developer for awhile. Recently, I got promoted within my team. Now I am responsible for application design and documentation, and am thinking of following the Scrum methodology.

We are starting a new project. As I am new to Design and Documentation, I am curious to know how many types of documents are required and in what order these documents must be written. Are there any references to required documents that I can look at?

Comment: I assume you will have read the "normal" design documents from previous projects. Is there something specific that does not meet your needs. Most of the time the manager just wants you to use whatever method or process ha sbeen in use in the company. Or did he tell you to go ahead and think of some new ways....

Comment: @HuibertGill I was asked to work on "High-level project Document" which all stake holders are interested to see. This should contain lot of UML in it. I don't have any reference documents. So wondering, if I can get any help here?

Comment: @HaBo UML document design is not a project management task. While you may have to perform the task *within* a project, that has nothing to do with the framework or the scope of the PM role. In fact, "where can I find..." questions are pretty much off-topic on every Stack Exchange site, so you'll have to do some independent research on that one. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

#### Scrum Does Not Prescribe Development Practices

Scrum is not a development methodology; it's a project management methodology. The Scrum process holds no specific answers for you from a requirements standpoint.

#### Scrum Provides a Framework for Your Questions

However, Scrum holds that the questions you are asking are part of the self-organizing that your team must do to be successful, including defining sprint goals and your team's "definition of done." As a result, you will need to look to your team (specifically including your Product Owner) to determine what specific design and documentation artifacts you need to produce to meet your sprint goals, and the prioritized order assigned to each of those artifacts.

#### See Also

- [Scrum Alliance - What Is Scrum?](http://www.scrumalliance.org/learn_about_scrum/)
- [Scrum (development)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29)

Comment: you are right. I have to start with preparing "High-level project Document" I wasn't sure what should be my check list in it. what all aspects of my project, should be covered in this document and how detailed is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

(I started this as a comment, maybe it should be just a comment)

"How detailed it should be"...

the scrum answer would be:

> as simple as it can be so that all parties know what to expect from
>   each other....

I know this does not help you much right now in the beginning.

Agile is based on continous improuvement, and that's not only about code, but also about how code is created, documented. CI is also about the comunication in the team and between stakeholders.

It is about finding the way with the least management overhead for your team to deliver results that satisfy your customer. Because this varies between teams, customers and countries, scrum does not give any details about how documents are created, only that **at least 3 documents be created**.

Comment: Some practitioners may argue over that definition, but the three documents you reference are generally agreed to be: product backlog, sprint backlog, and project/sprint burndown charts. http://www.scrum-agile-methodology.com/scrum-methodology.html